# How can I use Hyperlink Assertion using botium asserter for chatbot developed using watson?

Tags: automation, chatbot

I have Bot text response including hyper link. I want to put assertion for that hyperlink using botium bindning and botium asserter. How can I implement it?

e.g. bot response set in watson dialog (Text Response)
"Sure I can help you with. Please click Here

on above example I want to assert for google link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install the [Botium Hyperlink Asserter](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-asserter-basiclink)

   > npm install --save botium-asserter-basiclink
2. Adapt your botium.json

```
    {
      "botium": {
        "Capabilities": {
          ....
          "ASSERTERS": [
            {
              "ref": "HASLINK",
              "src": "botium-asserter-basiclink"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

3. Use the asserter in your convo file

```
...
#bot
HASLINK www.google.com
...
```

See the [Sample](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-asserter-basiclink/tree/master/samples) on Github